# how to use observer selector function in different ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, nsnotificationcenter

I have login and registration forms in my application. When user tap any textField I calculate the difference in height of keyboard and textField and scroll my view if needed.

For this I've added two observers in loginVC:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    println("keyb show")
    keyboardIsShown = true
    keyboardHeight = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue().height
    calculateAnimationValue()
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    println("keyb hide")
    keyboardIsShown = false
    animateViewMoving(false, moveValue: animationValue)
    animationValue = 0
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    pressedTextField = textField
    textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    if keyboardIsShown {
        calculateAnimationValue()
    }
}

func calculateAnimationValue() {
    if keyboardHeight != nil {
        var windowHeight = self.view.frame.height
        var textFieldY = pressedTextField.frame.origin.y
        var windowWithoutKeyboard = windowHeight - keyboardHeight - 44
        if textFieldY > windowWithoutKeyboard {
            if animationValue < (textFieldY - windowWithoutKeyboard) {
                animationValue = animationValue + textFieldY - windowWithoutKeyboard
                animateViewMoving(true, moveValue: animationValue)
            }
        }
    }
    println(animationValue)
}

func animateViewMoving (up: Bool, moveValue: CGFloat){
    var movementDuration: NSTimeInterval = 0.3
    var movement:CGFloat = (up ? -moveValue : moveValue)
    UIView.beginAnimations("animateView", context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(movementDuration)
    self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement)
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}
```

But I want to do the same in registrationVC.

How can I use keyboardWillShow, keyboardWillHide in another VC?

I've tried to add the same observers but then the application fires these methods in loginVC not in registrationVC.

Can someone help me?

**UPDATE: ------------------------**

```
class LogInViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        println("keyb show")
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        println("keyb hide")
    }
```

}

```
class RegistrationViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        println("keyb show2")
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        println("keyb hide2")
    }

    deinit {
        println("deinit")
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }
}
```

If I touch textField's on loginVC and segue to registerVC it works well and prints "keyb show2".

But if didn't touch textField's on loginVC and segue to registerVC and touch textField it prints "keyb show". Which is called from previous controller. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you register for the keyboard notifications in Register VC?

Comment: @manish_kumar Yes, I wrote the same code like in loginVC.

Comment: @manish_kumar Now, I found a strange issue. I start the application and if I touch any textField in loginVC, then I open registerVC and touch any textField the application run code from selector method that if is registerVC. But if I dont touch any textField in the loginVC and switch to registerVC and touch any textField it doent run selector method(. Sorry for my bad english(

Comment: Implement those methods and add observers in the register VC also. And don't forget to remove observers in `deinit`

Comment: @rshev check my updated answer please(

Comment: use `deinit` method in loginVC also.

Comment: @mikle94 firstly check for `deinit` in first view controller. if that doesn't help, then maybe you have a reference cycle somewhere. How do you display the second VC from the first one?